# Expected loss of Binomial Distribution

Tags: expected-value, binomial-distribution

I came across this problem in an additional exercises section without any solutions and I am wondering if my approach is correct. More specifically, with regard to the 'may or may not' phrasing as below.

**Question:** An electrician must check lightbulbs to detect defects. The employee must check exactly 100 lightbulbs on a given day. It is assumed that lightbulbs may be defects with probability p = 0.015, and that each lightbulb **may or may not be** a defect **independently** from the others. Each lightbulb is valued at $5

The loss that occurred on a given day is denoted L. This corresponds to the cost
for the process of checking n lightbulbs, which is equal to $\sqrt{n}$ dollars, plus the value of any defect lightbulbs found. **Calculate the expected loss**.

**My solution:**

n = 100 lightbulbs,  p = 0.015, x = number of defect lightbulbs. (Binomial)

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
P_{X}\;({X = x})\; &= \binom{n}{x} \cdot p^x(1-p)^{n-x} \\[5pt] &= \binom{100}{x} \cdot 0.015^x \cdot (1-0.015)^{100-x} \\[5pt] &= \binom{100}{x} \cdot 0.015^x \cdot 0.985^{100-x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Cost of checking 100 lightbulbs = $\sqrt{100}$ = $10

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
  Cost = \sum_{x=0}^{100} x \cdot P_{X}\, ({\{X = x}\}) \cdot 5 &= 100 * 0.015 * 5 = $7.5
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Expected Cost = 10 + 7.5 = $17.50